# Unable to get bearer token from Azure AD to use with API App

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-api-apps

I have an MVC application that needs to access private API App in Azure that is protected with Azure AD authentication. So I need to get Azure AD bearer token, transfer it into `Zumo-Auth` token and use it to access the API App.

I'm going through [this tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-authentication-client-flow/) and everything is working fine until the point when I need to request the token from `authContext`. Here is the snippet of a code:

```
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(
    "https://login.microsoftonline.com/MyADDomain.onmicrosoft.com");

ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(
    "04472E33-2638-FAKE-GUID-F826AF4928DB", 
    "OMYAPIKEY1x3BLAHEMMEHEHEHEHEeYSOMETHINGRc=");

// Get the AAD token.
var appIdUri = 
    "https://MyAppGateway-814485545465FAKE4d5a4532cd.azurewebsites.net/login/aad";

//var appIdUri = "https://MyADDomain.onmicrosoft.com/MyAppName";
//var appIdUri = "https://MyADDomain.onmicrosoft.com/";
//var appIdUri = "https://graph.windows.net";

AuthenticationResult result = 
    authContext.AcquireToken(appIdUri, credential); // <-- can't get the token from AD

// downhill from here
var aadToken = new JObject();
aadToken["access_token"] = result.AccessToken;
var appServiceClient = new AppServiceClient(
    "https://MyAppGateway-814485545465FAKE4d5a4532cd.azurewebsites.net/");

// Send the AAD token to the gateway and get a Zumo token
var appServiceUser = await appServiceClient.LoginAsync("aad", aadToken);
```

The line with `authContext.AcquireToken(appIdUri, credential)` is the one causing trouble.

If as `appIdUri` I give `https://MyAppGateway-814485545465FAKE4d5a4532cd.azurewebsites.net/login/aad`, I get exception:

> 400: AdalServiceException: AADSTS50001: Resource 'https://MyAppGateway-814485545465FAKE4d5a4532cd.azurewebsites.net/login/aad' is not registered for the account.

But this exact line is in the list of `Reply Url` in the AD Application

[image: Reply URI in Azure AD Application]

When I try to use `https://MyADDomain.onmicrosoft.com/MyAppName` or `https://MyADDomain.onmicrosoft.com/` as `appIdUri` I get a different exception message:

> 400: AdalServiceException: AADSTS50105: Application '04472E33-2638-FAKE-GUID-F826AF4928DB' is not assigned to a role for the application 'https://MyADDomain.onmicrosoft.com/MyAppName'

Or

> 400: AdalServiceException: AADSTS50105: Application '04472E33-2638-FAKE-GUID-F826AF4928DB' is not assigned to a role for the application 'https://MyADDomain.onmicrosoft.com/'

In both cases I had the `App ID URI` in the AD Application set to 'https://MyADDomain.onmicrosoft.com/MyAppName' or 'https://MyADDomain.onmicrosoft.com/'. And both of the names in the list of `Reply URL`.

Eventually after enough tries I have put `https://graph.windows.net` as `appIdUri` and got the bearer token back. But the token was given with expiry date in the past (about 1 minute in the past). So I could not do anything further with this. And got `401-Unauthenticated` when tried to use the token to login into API App.

What am I missing?

Comment: What is a `Zumo-Auth` token? How relevant is it to your question?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin `Zumo-Auth` is a token used by ApiApp and Mobile apps in Azure for authentication. I need it to authenticate with ApiApp. I guess for the question it is not that important as I can't seem to get the bearer token anyway and that is a step before.

Comment: Are you able to login via the browser? I.e. where you able to complete this step via the browser: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-dotnet-add-authentication/#prerequisites

Comment: Yes, logging in through the browser works with no issues - asks me for a MS password and lets me in to use the API. Though not sure now - I've changed so much during the experiments, I might have broken that. I'll double check when back in the office. Thanks for this pointer - to double check this did not come to my mind.

Comment: Well, if that's working, then my answer now might.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have gone ahead and followed the tutorial to which you referred: [Call an Azure API app from a web app client authenticated by Azure Active Directory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-authentication-client-flow/#create-and-secure-an-api-app-using-aad)

1. Create an Azure API Api that returns contact data
2. Deploy the API App to Azure App Service.
3. Secure the API App using Azure Active Directory.

Then I was able to retrieve the token, and as you can see from the following demo, my code is no different than your code, except that it using a later version of the `using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` libraries that use `Async`.

## Get access token from AAD

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Constants.AUTHORITY);
        var credential = 
            new ClientCredential(Constants.CLIENT_ID, Constants.CLIENT_SECRET);
        var result = (AuthenticationResult)authContext
            .AcquireTokenAsync(Constants.API_ID_URL, credential)
            .Result;
        var token = result.AccessToken;
        Console.WriteLine(token.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

## Constants

`AUTHORITY`. The first segment of this is https://login.microsoftonline.com. The final segment is an **allowed tenant**. We set the allowed tenant at portal.azure.com, going to the Gateway for our application, and choosing Settings > Identity > Azure Active Directory > Allowed Tenants. My tenant is bigfontoutlook.onmicrosoft.com.

`CLIENT_ID`. We retrieve this client id from the application that we added to Azure Active Directory. Find this at manage.windowsazure.com > Active Directory > Your Directory > APPLICATIONS > Your Application > CONFIGURE. Once we have retrieved it, we must add it to our Gateway's Azure Active Directory settings in the Client ID field.

`CLIENT_SECRET`. We create/retrieve this in the same location that we retrieve our client id.

`API_ID_URL`. We retrieve this within the Gateway blade for our Web API App by choosing Settings > Identity > Azure Active Directory > App URL.

Here are the ones that work for me.

```
class Constants
{
    public const string AUTHORITY =
     "https://login.microsoftonline.com/bigfontoutlook.onmicrosoft.com/";

    public const string CLIENT_ID = 
      "0d7dce06-c3e3-441f-89a7-f828e210ff6d";

    public const string CLIENT_SECRET =
      "AtRMr+Rijrgod4b9Q34i/UILldyJ2VO6n2jswkcVNDs=";

    public const string API_ID_URL = 
      "https://mvp201514929cfaaf694.azurewebsites.net/login/aad";
}
```

## Final decoded JWT

This is what the decoded JWT access token contains.

```
{
 typ: "JWT",
 alg: "RS256",
 x5t: "MnC_VZcATfM5pOYiJHMba9goEKY",
 kid: "MnC_VZcATfM5pOYiJHMba9goEKY"
}.
{
 aud: "https://mvp201514929cfc350148cfa5c9b24a7daaf694.azurewebsites.net/login/aad",
 iss: "https://sts.windows.net/0252f597-5d7e-4722-bafa-0b26f37dc14f/",
 iat: 1442346927,
 nbf: 1442346927,
 exp: 1442350827,
 ver: "1.0",
 tid: "0252f597-5d7e-4722-bafa-0b26f37dc14f",
 oid: "5a6f33eb-b622-4996-8a6a-600dce355389",
 sub: "5a6f33eb-b622-4996-8a6a-600dce355389",
 idp: "https://sts.windows.net/0252f597-5d7e-4722-bafa-0b26f37dc14f/",
 appid: "0d7dce06-c3e3-441f-89a7-f828e210ff6d",
 appidacr: "1"
}.
```

Note: It's a throwaway app in a throwaway active directory account with a throwaway resource group, so showing my security credentials is a non-issue.

## Diagram just to be sure :)

[image: Connecting the dots with Azure ADD]

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll give it a go tomorrow.

Comment: You know wha? I copied your code, put my guids, secrets and urls. And got the same damned exception again! Then I created a whole new Api app and a new AD Application. Copied the credentials and everything worked. Not sure what exactly was broken, but I suspect AD App was messed up beyond recognition.

Comment: Yup. Sometimes troubleshooting makes a mess :)

Comment: I just want to add that I ran into this exact same problem with the exact same errors and the exact same solution (start over and try again). The thing is, I've now started over and tried again about 8 times and only 5 of the 8 times has it worked. Something seems to be unreliable with this - I don't know if this is due to the Preview'ness of the tooling or what, but it doesn't seem to be terribly reliable. :-/

Comment: @Jaxidian I was facing something like that once with OAuth, and it turned out to be the difference between using HTTP and HTTPS. Have you checked that?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin Thanks. Fortunately (unfortunately?) I figured out the unpredictable behavior. It's predictable once you account for delayed engagement of the "User assignment required?" setting. With that enabled (and waiting a minute), it 100% fails with the OP's error. No matter what, I cannot seem to figure out how to "assign" the client application to the web api application.