# Azure AD Application - Require Role Assignment + Add a role assignment for an Application?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

I have an MVC Web Application (WebAPI + Angular) deployed to Azure as a Web App (not API App) that is setup to be secured using Settings -> Authentication / Authorization -> AAD -> Express. This created an AD Application with the same name as the Web App, and as a normal web user (in the directory, using OAuth) this works as expected.

But I also have external automation that needs to call the WebAPI controllers directly, so I need to programmatically get a Bearer token to pass along with those requests.

This all works OK when "USER ASSIGNMENT REQUIRED TO ACCESS APP" == NO. But this won't suffice because everyone in the Directory shouldn't have access to this app.

Flipping that switch results in the error:

> Application 'AppId' is not assigned to a role for the application 'AppId'.

The code being used:

```
    var aadLoginUri = "http://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}";
    var tenantId = "[xxx].onmicrosoft.com";
    var authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadLoginUri, tenantId);
    var clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];
    var clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"];

    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
    ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
    AuthenticationResult authResult = authContext.AcquireToken(clientId, clientCredential);
```

**How can I add a role assignment for an Application?** 

*(as opposed to for a user)*

I tried utilizing the 'permissions to other applications' section, but an app cannot be added to itself. To see if this would solve the problem from another app, I went ahead and created one and was able to add the App & set Delegated Permissions to 'Access [App Name]'. But just as before, this only works if user assignment is not required to access the app. Afterwards `AcquireToken()` throws the same exception.

It seems this issue [could be solved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32594294) by decoupling our API from the Angular app, hosting the API as an API App (with a Gateway), but that's not an option at the moment. Also [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication/#advanced) says this new Auth feature "*replaces the App Service gateway for most applications*" and [this blog post](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-app-service-authentication-authorization/) announcing the feature in November says "*We recommend web and mobile applications use this feature instead of the App Service gateway going forward*" so I wonder if this just hasn't made it into the UI & perhaps it's possible to add app role assignments via the app manifest (tried, failed), graph/service-mgmt api, powershell, etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The key is to define the correct appRoles (with the correct allowedMemberType) in the manifest.

In the Azure Portal, configure the following:

In the **resource** that needs to be accessed, open the **manifest** ('App Registrations' blade). In the **appRoles** array, add two roles:

- One of allowedMemberType 'Application'
- One of allowedMemberType 'User'

Save the manifest.

Next, in the **client app** that needs to access the resource:

- Browse to '**Required Permissions**' and click 'Add'
- Search for the resource you want to access
- In the 'Enable Access' section, under 'Application Permissions', select the role you just configured
- Save and click 'Grant permissions'

To configure the **user permissions**:

- Browse to the 'Enterprise Applications' blade
- Select 'All Application', then select the correct app
- Click 'Users and Groups'
- Assign users to roles

In the Properties section, keep the 'User assignment required?' checkbox enabled. This will restrict access to configured users only.

Now you can access the resource both as a user and as an application.

Comment: Thanks. I had forgotten about this. It's much more straightforward now than it was 2 years ago :)

Comment: @JoeBrockhaus have youu tried to programatically assign users to apps

Comment: Can you use one appRole that's for both 'User' and 'Application' or is there a particular reason you need two roles, one for each allowedMemberType?

Comment: No idea where this "Required Permissions" is. Either I can't find it or (most likely) the entire process in Azure has since changed. I'm about to scream trying to get this working.

Comment: It has changed. Look for "Api Permissions" inside your client's App Registration. Add a permission to your server (the protected resource), choosing "Application Permissions" when it asks you "What type of permission?"

Answer (score 0):

> **How can I add a role assignment for an Application?**

1) Download Manifest from Application page as follow:
[image]

2)Add role content in Manifest like below. An user can be assigned to an application as an user role, **group, application** also can be assigned to application as a role.

```
"appRoles": [
{
"allowedMemberTypes": [
    "User"
  ],
  "description": "Admins can manage roles and perform all actions.",
  "displayName": "Global Admin",
  "id": "7c93906c-71fa-4e5b-b1da-21b073d298fd",
  "isEnabled": true,
  "value": "Admin"
}
]
```