# How to authenticate non azure Application in Azure API APP which has AAD authentication in place?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am having WEB API App which is deployed on Azure App service. Currently only AAD users can be authenticated and able to access API methods. Now we have another requirement where our API methods will be called by one of the on premise application. Could you please let me know how we can get service principal in order to access my cloud API methods from this on premise(non azure) application. Is there any way present in Azure to achieve above requirement.

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: Java spring boot for API.Client will be react js

Comment: Another client can be Java spring boot deployed on premise

Comment: Have you tried [`msal-react`](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-react/README.md) and [`Azure AD Spring Boot Starter client library for Java`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/active-directory-spring-boot-starter-readme?view=azure-java-stable), in the samples, their resources are both Microsoft Graph, just change them to the App ID URI of your web api AD App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no official example ready.

You need to create the app registration which represents your WEB API App by following [Protected web API: App registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-registration#if-your-web-api-is-called-by-a-daemon-app).

Since your on-premise app is equivalent to a daemon app, you should expose application permissions like this: [If your web API is called by a daemon app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-registration#exposing-application-permissions-app-roles).

Then you can follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-sign-user-app-registration?tabs=aspnetcore) to create the app registration / service principal (represents your on-premise app) which will be used to authenticate to your WEB API App. And you need to add application permissions (which are exposed in the previous step) into this app registration by following [Add permissions to access your web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis#add-permissions-to-access-your-web-api).

At last, use [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to get the access token. You can use this access token to access your WEB API.

[Client Credentials sample](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java/wiki/Client-Credentials) in msal-java for your reference.

Here is [a similar post and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32589063/unable-to-get-bearer-token-from-azure-ad-to-use-with-api-app?answertab=votes#tab-top) (it's c# but the principle is the same).